# PHP5: Objects reference

Tags: php, oop, reference, circular-reference

I'm writing some entities class in php, that may point between each other with a repository class (to avoid to query too much the database using a local entity repository):

```
class Foo
{
    public $fooId;
    public $bar;
    function __construct($entity_id)
    {
        /**
        * Some Database stuff to get Foo object based on $entity_id
        **/
        $this->bar = Repository::get('Bar', $databaseStuff->barId);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public $foo;
    function __construct($entity_id)
    {
        /**
        * Some Database stuff to get Bar object based on $entity_id
        **/
        $this->bar = Repository::get('Bar', $databaseStuff->barId);
    }
}

class Repository
{
    private static $entities = [];
    /**
     * @param string $entity_name
     * @param int $entity_id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function &get($entity_name, $entity_id)
    {
        $entity_name = ucfirst(strtolower($entity_name));
        if(!isset(self::$entities[$entity_name][$entity_id]))
        {
            self::$entities[$entity_name][$entity_id] =& $entity_name($entity_id);
        }
        return self::$entities[$entity_name][$entity_id];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo(1337);
```

**The problem is** that i get a sort of timeout/stack overflow probably due to the fact of `$foo->bar` is a reference to a Bar object, but `$bar->foo` is a reference to a Foo object, etc...

> - I did not forgot to declare my function to return a reference using &get(), am i right?
> - My class is instantiated with =& operator.

What could be wrong in my code (or in my logic) ?
Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen a function by-reference..

Comment: PHP don't handle very well circular references, and some things are known to cause issues. For instance, if you try to `serialize()` that, it will produce output undefinitely until it either run out of memory or time. The garbage collector (or at least I think it is the gc that causes that) will also have some nasty performance issues and eventual crashes. I've had plenty of experience with that lately, and decided its best to avoid doing circular references in PHP.

Comment: How to deal with it so? In my case, i have an "User" class and an "Asset" class. The user have an avatar (which is an asset object), and the asset have an user (which is the user object).

Comment: Also, you are not calling `get()` at any point as far as I can tell. You should be calling `&Repository::get()` instead of just `Repository()`. Functions that return a reference must be called with `&` too in order to work. However, if you are returning an object, you can drop the whole reference thing. Objects are already implicitly passed by reference. To pass a copy of an object in PHP you must explicitly say it, with `clone $object`.

Comment: It's a bad copy/paste, i'm effectively calling Repository::get()

Comment: This `self::$entities[$entity_name][$entity_id] =& $entity_name($entity_id)` should be `self::$entities[$entity_name][$entity_id] = new $entity_name($entity_id)`, you forgot the **new**. Since its an object you can drop all `&`.

Comment: @Havenard I did it but it still not work ..

Comment: Thats because this is recursively calling itself undefinitely. You create `Foo()`, and its constructor tries to create a `Bar()`, that tries to create `Foo()` again, all that happens without ever filling a single value in `Repository::$entities` because they keep calling each other before that operation can be done even once.

Comment: If it is in the constructor or a method called later it's the same thing, right?

Comment: If you call it later it should solve the problem, because this time `Repository::$entities` will be set and it wont create it again.

Comment: Ohh, i think i got it, the Object did not really exists yet as soon the constructor execution is not totally finished.

Comment: Yeap, they keep calling each other without ever returning a value to be inserted in `Repository::$entities`, so the loop never ends.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for saving me hours. I'd like to reward you, but i'm too new yet :/

Comment: Where is the "solved" button ?

Comment: The best thing to do is to post your final result as an answer to your own question, then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If I see it right, the constructor of Bar tries to create new Bar.
I suppose such a nested constructing will never end. Its the same e.g. when a function calls itself recursively with no way to exit.
The script will even not come to writing into Repository.

Ever tried xdebug? That could show the problem quite quickly.

And btw there are possibli bad Copy/Paste. The comment in class Foo does not match the line fallowing it. And you are setting $this->bar in class Bar, but only class variable $foo is declared.

Comment: Yes it's a bad copy/paste, and no i never tried xdebug, probably because it's too complicated to configure.